# Install postgis on ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Tags: postgis

I am trying to install postgis on ubuntu Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

I search the repo and find a package called postgresql-9.1-postgis. I then installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis
```

It also installed the following dependencies:

```
libgeos-3.2.2 libgeos-c1 libproj0 postgis proj-data
```

I then thought I could easily do (inside my schema):

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

But I instead got the wonderful error detailed below:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory


********** Error **********

ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
Any idea how I can finalize the installation so that I can use the damn extension?
```

Can anyone help?

Ta

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Postgis version. This command installs old version of Postgis.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis
```

Install Postgis version 2 from source and try.

[Here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch02.html#id354505) is official installation guide.